# How does the boundary property usually work in PDE?

Tags: soft-question, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

This may be related to the question [*Is the hypersurface of class $C^k$ a $C^k$-differentiable manifold?*](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44786/9464). In almost every chapter of a PDE textbook(e.g. Folland's *Introduction to Partial Differential Equations*), the boundary of the domain is assumed to have some properties. The most common assumption is about the "*smoothness*"(I call it so, whether appropriate or not). For example, in Chapter 3 in Folland's book, there is a sentence as following:

"In this chapter $\Omega$ will be a fixed bounded domain in ${\mathbb R}^n$ with $C^2$ **boundary** $S$,..."

It seems that this assumption is always used *implicitly*. I can never understand how it actually work. I can only know superficially that $C^2$ means the coordinates charts are $C^2$-compatible in the definition of differentiable structure. Nothing more. **Is there a rule of thumb that how this assumption is used?**

It may be too vague to ask such question without a concrete proposition/theorem which has such assumption. Any suggestion for a good modification of the question will be really welcomed.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: that hypothesis allows you to prove theorems on simpler domains (e.g. semispaces, spheres) then transfer them via a change of coordinates over more general domains *provided* their boundary is sufficiently smooth.

Comment: I suspect in many cases the nature of the boundary isn't terribly important -- for example, think about the heat equation in the plane.  The boundary does not need to be $C^2$ for the main theorems about heat flow.  I think in many cases it just makes life a lot easier to assume the boundary is nice -- for the sake of proving theorems quickly without too much technical fussing-about.  If you need more flexible boundary conditions, then you have to think more carefully about whatever PDE you're interested in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the cases you need it is for prescribing boundary values. Just consider the change of variable formula. To define a $k$th order derivative space on the boundary of a set, you need that boundary to be described by a function that is at least $W^{k,\infty}$ (which is the Lipschitz space $C^{k-1,1}$).

Similarly, the usual technique in proving boundary estimates for PDEs is to "straighten out" the boundary so that you can work in the case where your domain is the half-space. To do this change of variable, and preserve strong solutions in a uniform way, requires certain minimum differentiability assumptions on the boundary.

Another case where it is used is that for a bounded domain with $C^2$ boundary, the boundary is compact, and therefore as a lower bound on the radius of curvature. This is then sufficient to guarantee uniform *interior* and *exterior* sphere conditions† on the boundary, and thus allows you to prove strong maximum principle for second order elliptic operators on the domain.

† The sphere conditions are conditions on the "one sided" smoothness of the boundary. Let $\Omega$ be an open domain and let $x_0$ be a point on the boundary $\partial\Omega$. The boundary $\partial\Omega$ is said to satisfy an *interior sphere condition* with radius $r$ at $x_0$ if there exists $x'\in\Omega$ such that the open ball of radius $r$ around $x'$, which we denote $B_r(x')$, satisfies $B_r(x') \subset \Omega$ and $x_0 \in \partial B_r(x')$. Immediately you see that if $\partial\Omega$ satisfies the interior sphere condition with radius $r$, then it will also for all radii $r' < r$. The *exterior* sphere condition is defined analogously, with $x'$ and $B_r(x')$ required to reside to the exterior of $\Omega$.

Observe that the sphere conditions give "one-sided" bounds on the "radius of curvature". For example, let $\Omega = \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y > |x| \}$. Then at the corner at the origin, $\Omega$ does not satisfy the interior sphere condition for any $r$, but it satisfies exterior sphere conditions for any positive radius.

Lastly, *uniformity* is just the statement that $\exists r_0$ st. $\forall x\in\partial\Omega$, $\partial\Omega$ satisfies an interior/exterior sphere condition of radius $r_0$ at $x$.

Comment: Why is there a "community wiki" tag after you answer?

Comment: What does the "uniform interior and exterior sphere conditions on the boundary" mean? I guess it's something like the uniform convergence of the inward and outward directional derivative defined on the boundary?

Comment: (a) I community wiki'd it because it is more of a summary + elaboration of what dissonance and Ryan Budney already mentioned in their comments. ... and I am somewhat surprised that the new SE FAQ no longer mentioned community wiki. The idea is that I don't get "credit" (in terms of rep and stuff) for this answer, and anybody is free to edit the answer (whereas for non-CW posts, there is a minimum rep requirement for editing other people's posts).

Comment: (b) a point $x_0\in\partial\Omega$ is said to satisfy the interior sphere condition if there exists a point $x'\in\Omega$ and an open ball $B$ centered at $x'$ such that $B\subset \Omega$ and $x_0\in\partial B$. In other words, you can fit a (small) ball completely inside $\Omega$ such that $x_0$ sits on the boundary of the ball. The exterior sphere condition is analogous, but with the sphere sitting outside of $\Omega$. Uniformity means that one can give a lower bound of the radius of the relevant balls regardless of which point $x\in\partial\Omega$.

Comment: +1. Now I see. Thanks for your elaboration. May I ask you to put the comment (b) to your answer?